# What are oracle services going to look like on Cardano?

Tags: oracles, community

Can we expect an effort from IOHK to implement oracle services? Or should this be community driven?

Comment: These answers are pretty old but I think the question is still valid. What is the most current status for Oracles in Cardano as of now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An early oracle-like service [nut.link](https://nut.link/) run by the community is already running. It will not provide data to smart contacts, but various dApps might be able to consume its resources if they can read on-chain data.

As for real oracle solutions that will be able to provide inputs to smart contacts, we will have a lot of them, from community to IOG.

In fact, [most of the work on oracle pools](https://github.com/Emurgo/Emurgo-Research/blob/master/oracles/Oracle-Pools.md) has already been done by Emurgo, not IOG. And implemented on Ergo.

Answer (score 2):

In Dec 2020 IOHK (IOG) announced that they intended to partner with Wolfram on Oracles for Cardano.  Initial phases were planned to commence in Q2-Q3 of 2021.

Given the timeframe, I believe they will be delivered as part of the smart contract functionality expected to be fully delivered in Aug 2021.

Comment: Do you have references for these dates, please?